# Convert suit font to web font

Tags: css, fonts, webfonts

I have a font that I'm trying to use for a website demo. Below are the font file name & extension.

[image]

It looks like the fonts have no extension and then in the folder contains the suitcase ( Interstate.scr )

Is there a way to convert this font to webfont, or atleast a ttf?

I only need regular, light, bold, and black weights.

Thanks :)

Comment: An `scr` font, `screen font`, is a bitmap font, it cannot be converted to a webfont.

Comment: @APAD1 is there no way to convert it to a ttf or anything??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using [onlinefontconverter.com](https://onlinefontconverter.com)

Answer (score 0):

You can try font-face generators online or for example u can use this hope it helps.

http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator

Comment: I tried to use that site but it wont let me select the files when I upload them :/